# Area chart - start filling from non zero y value

Tags: plotly.js

I am trying to create an area chart that looks like this where I am using bars:

```
 var trace1 = {
  x: ['2013-10-04 9:00:00', '2013-10-04 9:30:00', '2013-10-04 10:00:00', '2013-10-04 11:00:00', '2013-10-04 11:30:00', '2013-10-04 12:30:00'], 
  y: [20, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20], 
  type: 'bar',
  base: [5,5,5,5,5,5],
  mode: 'none'
};
var data = [trace1];
myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, data);
```

[Pen](https://codepen.io/MZolotoy/pen/yLyEgjN)

As you can see y axis starts from non zero value. Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code to start y-axis 0

```
var layout = {
  yaxis: {
    rangemode: 'tozero' //or below
    //range: [0, 25]
}
};

Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, data, layout);
```

Comment: Can that be [10,25]?

Comment: If this is the range you want, yes it could be true